# fixing css after rake:assets precompile - how to not run capistrano

Tags: heroku, rake, capistrano, asset-pipeline, precompile

I recently changed an image on the landing page of my herokuapp built in rails. I realized that everything worked fine except that the landing page threw a 500 error. Upon some research I realized i should run `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile`

After doing so, the images and some of the styling came back but some of it is still screwy and I cannot understand why.

I've read through just about every stackoverflow thread, the [rails guide on the asset pipeline](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html), and others but I can't get it to work. I've amended the files that need amending 
as far as I know but nothing is working to make the styling revert to how it should be.

However, on the rails guide it notes that there are two caveats to locally precompile:

> You must not run the Capistrano deployment task that precompiles
>   assets. You must change the following two application configuration
>   settings. In config/environments/development.rb, place the following
>   line:
>
> config.assets.prefix = "/dev-assets"

I did the change within development.rb but I am not sure on how I can not run Capistrano. I dont think I'm doing that so maybe it's throwing some things off - idk, but each time I try to recompile now, the rake aborts. Any help is very much appreciated.